Use socat to bridge CanFD messages
Is it possible to bridge to can interfaces via socat?
My setup looks something like this:
HOST A                       Host B
vcan0           <->          vcan0

Where i have 2 hosts with a can interface and i want to bridge them ideally via socat.
I got as far as sending can messages which the following config.
But CanFD messages are just silently dropped and are not forwarded to the remote vcan interface. (I would like to avoid using something like cannelloni.)
Server
sudo socat INTERFACE:vcan0,pf=29,type=3,prototype=1 TCP-LISTEN:2000,fork,reuseaddr,nodelay

Client
sudo socat INTERFACE:vcan0,pf=29,type=3,prototype=1 TCP:SERVERIP:2000,nodelay

Is forwarding CanFD even possible with socat?
More debugging
Running socat with -d -d -d shows that the socat process doesn't even register CanFD frames.
For a can frame these 2 messages are produced:
2024/12/13 09:26:12 socat[8514] N local address: AF=29 AF=29 0x0000060000000400000000000000
2024/12/13 09:26:12 socat[8514] I transferred 16 bytes from 7 to 5

And nothing for CanFD.

I'm not familiar with canfd, but if it's frame/packet based, by encapsulating it in a TCP stream, you're losing the framing. UDP might be preferable.

"Is it possible to bridge to can interfaces via socat?" Bridge TO a CAN interface FROM ...  what?

@Seamus i thought it was clear for the socat i shared but i tried to update the question with a bit more details its basically from CAN to CAN

@StéphaneChazelas Im not sure im fully understand what you are saying but i tried UDP-RECV and UDP-DATAGRAM and it suffers from the same issue

Try running those socat with a few -d -d -d or under strace -f to see whether they're doing something and that it's what you expect them to do.

Thanks for the clarification... I'll guess that socat can bridge different CAN terminals, but I'm afraid I've never done that, so probably can't help much. One thing that occurs to me is that you've probably got some hardware interfaces (i.e. devices) on your Linux system. IIRC, socat can forward traffic between devices. Does that give you any ideas?

it feels a bit like socat isn't even registering canfd frames at all

Did you set the mtu to 72 to enable canfd?

Yes canfd frames are visible on the interface itself so im running a candump on the interface and see the canfd frame on the side where im sending the frame
